# How to change array of arrays into hashmap?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I stuck in a situation, I have an array of array structure how can I make 
it hash like below:-

**Example:**

```
[[378, 1], [144, 1], [144, 1], [144, 3], [144, 7], [144, 6], [144, 8], [144, 8], [809, 1], [809, 1], [809, 8]]
```

**Convert to:**

```
{378=>[1], 144=>[1,3,7,6,8], 809=>[1,8]}
```

means take the first element as key and make the second element in another array as value matched to key.

I tried below method but failed in one use case:

```
raw_hash = arr.group_by { |sub_arr| sub_arr[0] }
modified_hash = {}
raw_hash.each do |k, arr|
   modified_hash[k] = [ arr.flatten.uniq - [ k ] ].flatten
end
```

**failed use-case is if first element and second element both will same then it will make unique and subtract second value**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by the first element of the array and then chose the last second elements of the grouped values.

```
a = [[378, 1], [144, 1], [144, 1], [144, 3], [144, 7], [144, 6], [144, 8], [144, 8], [809, 1], [809, 1], [809, 8]] 
a.group_by(&:first).map{|k, v| [k, v.map(&:last)]}.to_h
# => {378=>[1], 144=>[1, 1, 3, 7, 6, 8, 8], 809=>[1, 1, 8]}
```

EDIT:

If you want to have a unique values, add `uniq` to the map that collects them:

```
a.group_by(&:first).map{|k, v| [k, v.map(&:last).uniq]}.to_h
#=> {378=>[1], 144=>[1, 3, 7, 6, 8], 809=>[1, 8]}
```

Comment: Updated, see now.

Comment: This solution is ok for the instance from the question, but extremely slow and inefficient if array is quite big.

Comment: How big is _quite big_ to make the difference significant?

Comment: @mrzasa you can perform benchmarking, it doesn't matter actually :) If we can do something obviously faster and consume less memory why just don't do it? :)

Comment: I could, but it's you who raised that point, so I'll leave you the pleasure to defend it ;-).
The reason to use this solution is that it IMO it's more elegant and ruby-ish. Of course it's mostly personal preference and as we've known for 2k years _de gustibus..._ ;-)

Comment: what do you mean by `more elegant and ruby-ish`?(just curious)

Comment: chaining `map`s & `group_by` in opposition to `each` and mutating arrays (I know that too many maps causes GC overhead).

Answer (score 4):

Just use `each_with_object`, it is faster and consumes less memory than @mrzasa's approach:

```
array.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) do |(first, last), m|  
  m[first] |= [last]
end
#=> {378=>[1], 144=>[1, 3, 7, 6, 8], 809=>[1, 8]}
```

But for the uniqueness the simplest probably would be using `Set`:

```
array.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Set.new }) do |(first, last), m|  
  m[first] << last 
end
#=> {378=>#<Set: {1}>, 144=>#<Set: {1, 3, 7, 6, 8}>, 809=>#<Set: {1, 8}>}
```

Comment: `|(first, last), m|` nice